# Extracting characters from an input string vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, character, extract

Hey guys I'm stuck with this question. Please help.

I want to write a program that can extract alphabetical characters and special characters from an input string. An alphabetical character is any character from "a" to "z"(capital letters and numbers not included") a special character is any other character that is not alphanumerical.

Example:

```
string = hello//this-is-my-string@capetown

alphanumerical characters = hellothisismystringcapetown

special characters = //---@
```

Now my question is this:

1. How do I loop through all the characters?

   (the for loop I'm using reads like this for `x = 0` to `strname.length`)...is this correct?
2. How do I extract characters to a string?
3. How do I determine special characters?

any input is greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each character as follows:

```
For Each _char As Char In strname
    'Code here
Next
```

or

```
For x as integer = 0 to strname.length - 1
    'Code here
Next
```

or you can use Regex to replace the values you do not need in your string (I think this may be faster but I am no expert) Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

**Edit**

The replacement code will look something as follows although I am not so sure what the regular expression (variable called pattern currently only replacing digits) would be:

```
Dim pattern As String = "(\d+)?" 'You need to update the regular expression here
Dim input As String = "123//hello//this-is-my-string@capetown"
Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to keep the values, you'll want to loop through your string. Keeping a list of characters as a result will come in handy since you can build a fresh string later. Then take advantage of a simple Regex test to determine where to place things. The psuedo code looks something like this.

```
Dim alphaChars As New List(Of String)
Dim specialChars As New List(Of String)

For Each _char As Char in testString

   If Regex.IsMatch(_char, "[a-z]")) Then

      alphaChars.Add(_char)

   Else

      specialChars.Add(_char)

   End If

Next
```

Then If you need to dump your results into a full string, you can simply use

```
String.Join(String.Empty, alphaChars.ToArray())
```

Note that this code makes the assumption that ANYTHING else than a-z is considered a special character, so if needs be  you can do a second regular expression in your else clause to test for you special characters in a similar manner. It really depends on how much control you have over the input.

Comment: I think what he wants is to not add A-Z, 0-9 as specialChars, so he'd need an additional elseIf doing nothing